# How to get Monday, Sunday based on a Week Number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, date

I have a week number (e.g. 23) and I'd like to get the dates for Monday and Sunday of that week.
I am assuming Monday as the first day of the week (e.g. I have `SET DATEFIRST 1` in my script).

Comment: For this year, is 3-Jan-2011 the 2nd Monday(*) or the 1st Monday. For the former, there would be no Monday in the "first week of 2011"

Comment: Define week 1 please. ISO? Country? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Examples

Comment: It makes sense to define it in a way that is reversible using Datepart(Week) in SQL Server, which my answer will provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @startweek1 datetime
SET DATEFIRST 1

--first monday of year
SELECT @startweek1 = DATEADD(day, 8-DATEPART(weekday, '2011-01-01'), '2011-01-01')

--day based
SELECT
    DATEADD(day, 22 * 7, @startweek1) AS MondayWeek23,
    DATEADD(day, 23 * 7 -1 , @startweek1) AS SundayWeek23

--week based
SELECT
    DATEADD(week, 22, @startweek1) AS MondayWeek23,
    DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(week, 23 , @startweek1)) AS SundayWeek23
```

Edit:

This solution works if week 1 does not start on day 1 as Andomar said

Edit 2:

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Examples): 2008-12-29 is day 1 of week 1 of 2009 in ISO.

And [week numbers vary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-day_week#Week_numbering) as Andomar said

Cyberkiwi mentioned this code is wrong for 2007: it's wrong far more often than that. The same applies to his code too which matches 2007 but is equally wrong for the rest.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it, this is the right approach.  Sometimes the first week must have 3 full days in the new year, so depending on your country this might get even more complex.

Comment: @Andomar: I didn't know that. Having week 53 is bad enough let alone some special rules about start of year

Comment: @cyberkiwi: The constants might be off, but the idea is good.  On my system it should be `DATEADD(day, 2-DATEPART(weekday, '2007-01-01'), '2007-01-01')` (i.e. just change 8 to 2)

Comment: @gbn `Sorry for not being OCD enough to try` Poor excuse for not providing good tested code on a public forum, with a slant at labeling others as `OCD`. I demand an apology

Comment: @cyberwiki; You appear to have the same method as gbn, `X - datepart(dw, ...)`, which is the good approach.

Comment: @andomar It looks similar but it works. That statement is like saying `your approach uses ANSI-SQL` or `you use row_number() too`; holds no water.

Comment: @Andomar can you explain the use of the 8 /2 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @StartDate datetime;
Set @StartDate = '20110101';

With StartOfWeek As
    (
    Select DateAdd(
        week
        , 23
        , DateAdd(
            d 
            , -(DatePart(dw, @StartDate) - 1)
            , @StartDate
            ) ) As Sunday
    )
Select Sunday, DateAdd(d,1,Sunday) As Monday
From StartOfWeek
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the DATEFIRST variable to set the start day of the week. By default, the week starts on Sunday(7). In order to start with Monday, we will set its value to 1.

```
# Printing default value
Select @@DATEFIRST; -- This will give 7 value i.e. default value

# Changing first day of the week to Monday.
Declare @CurrentWeekNumber int
SET DATEFIRST 1
set @CurrentWeekNumber= (SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()))
select @CurrentWeekNumber
```

PS: Changes to DATEFIRST are valid for current session i.e. it doesn't impact other DB queries which might rely on different week start day.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. This provided answer may be correct, but **it could benefit from an explanation**. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

***Note:** Any answer that starts with assuming year is 2011 might as well take a static first date, i.e. by replacing @firstMon in my last query below with just the static date '20101227'.*

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

declare @targetYear int
declare @targetWeek int
select @targetYear = 2011, @targetWeek = 23

declare @firstMon datetime
set @firstMon = dateadd(d,1-datepart(dw, right(@targetYear,4)+'0101'),right(@targetYear,4)+'0101')

select
    MonOfTargetWeek = dateadd(week, @targetWeek-1, @firstMon),
    SunOfTargetWeek = dateadd(week, @targetWeek-1, @firstMon+6)
```

And the real, final query - which returns a Mon/Sun of NULL when it doesn't exist in that week, such as Mon of partial-week-one or Sun of partial-week-53

```
;with tmp(Mon, Sun) as (
select
    MonOfTargetWeek = dateadd(week, @targetWeek-1, @firstMon),
    SunOfTargetWeek = dateadd(week, @targetWeek-1, @firstMon+6)
)
select
    RealMonday = case when Year(Mon)=@targetYear then Mon end,
    RealSunday = case when Year(Sun)=@targetYear then Sun end
from tmp
```

### For GBN's claim that this answer is wrong (within his answer), I submit below the proof of correctness

I have turned the code into a function.

```
CREATE function dbo.getMonSunForWeek(@targetYear int, @targetWeek int)
returns table as return
with pre(firstMon) as (
    select dateadd(d,1-datepart(dw, right(@targetYear,4)+'0101'),right(@targetYear,4)+'0101'))
, tmp(Mon, Sun) as (
select
    dateadd(week, @targetWeek-1, firstMon),
    dateadd(week, @targetWeek-1, firstMon+6)
    from pre
)
select
    Mon, Sun,
    RealMonday = case when Year(Mon)=@targetYear then Mon end,
    RealSunday = case when Year(Sun)=@targetYear then Sun end
from tmp
GO
```

And below I present the ENTIRE range of years and weeks (1-53) for the years from 1950 through 2047.  In **EVERY SINGLE** case, when the Monday/Sunday has been determined, and **working backwards using `DATEPART(week)`**, SQL Server agrees with the week numbering from the function.

```
set datefirst 1;
select
    [Year]  = years.number,
    [Week]  = weeks.number,
    [Mon]   = fun.realmonday,
    [Sun]   = fun.realsunday,
    [WeekX] = isnull(datepart(week, fun.realmonday), datepart(week, fun.realsunday)),
    [MonX]  = fun.Mon,
    [SunX]  = fun.Sun
from master..spt_values years
inner join master..spt_values weeks on weeks.type='P' and weeks.number between 1 and 53
cross apply dbo.getMonSunForWeek(years.number, weeks.number) fun
where years.type='P' and years.number between 1950 and 2047
order by [year], [Week]
```

Output around the 2005-2006 changeover

```
                                                 when including prior/next year
Year Week Mon-of-week Sun-of-week datepart(week) Mon  -and-  Sun 
2005 52   2005-12-19  2005-12-25  52             2005-12-19  2005-12-25
2005 53   2005-12-26  NULL        53             2005-12-26  2006-01-01
2006  1   NULL        2006-01-01   1             2005-12-26  2006-01-01
2006  2   2006-01-02  2006-01-08   2             2006-01-02  2006-01-08
```

Comment: Fails for 2006. It gives 26 Dec 2005 which is week 52 in 2005. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Examples I'm OCD enough to check *why* we're both wrong...

Comment: @gbn - It doesn't fail, you're just not reading correctly. See part added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

A calendar table makes this kind of date query pretty simple. A calendar table just has the relevant calendar details calculated and stored at load time instead of calculated at run time. Depending on the application, that can speed things up a lot. This way is dbms agnostic; it just uses literals in the WHERE clause.

```
select cal_date from calendar
where iso_year = 2011 
  and iso_week = 23
  and cal_dow in ('Mon', 'Sun');
```

And another way that relies only on having a table of dates.

```
select cal_date from calendar
where extract(isoyear from cal_date) = 2011 
  and extract(week from cal_date) = 23 
  and (extract(isodow from cal_date) = 1 or
       extract(isodow from cal_date) = 7);
```

EXTRACT() is standard SQL, but I'm not sure whether the names of the subfields isoyear, week, isodow are standard SQL.

Answer (score -1):

You might try some dateadd logic...

```
dateadd(week, 23, '2011-01-01')

dateadd(day, 7, dateadd(week, 23, '2011-01-01'))
```

UPDATE:

```
select dateadd(day, 23, dateadd(week, 23, '2011-01-01')) , Datename(weekday,dateadd(day, 23, dateadd(week, 23, '2011-01-01')));
// RETURNS 7/4/2011,    Monday
select  Datename(weekday,dateadd(day, 23, dateadd(week, 23, '2011-01-01')));
// RETURNS  Monday
```

EXAMPLE FROM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

```
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = '2007-01-01 13:10:10.1111111'
SELECT 'year', DATEADD(year,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'quarter',DATEADD(quarter,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'month',DATEADD(month,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'dayofyear',DATEADD(dayofyear,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'day',DATEADD(day,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'week',DATEADD(week,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'weekday',DATEADD(weekday,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'hour',DATEADD(hour,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'minute',DATEADD(minute,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'second',DATEADD(second,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'millisecond',DATEADD(millisecond,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'microsecond',DATEADD(microsecond,1,@datetime2)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'nanosecond',DATEADD(nanosecond,1,@datetime2);
/*
Year         2008-01-01 13:10:10.1111111
quarter      2007-04-01 13:10:10.1111111
month        2007-02-01 13:10:10.1111111
dayofyear    2007-01-02 13:10:10.1111111
day          2007-01-02 13:10:10.1111111
week         2007-01-08 13:10:10.1111111
weekday      2007-01-02 13:10:10.1111111
hour         2007-01-01 14:10:10.1111111
minute       2007-01-01 13:11:10.1111111
second       2007-01-01 13:10:11.1111111
millisecond  2007-01-01 13:10:10.1121111
microsecond  2007-01-01 13:10:10.1111121
nanosecond   2007-01-01 13:10:10.1111111
*/
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `dateadd(week, ...` just seems to add 7 days.  So using this method in 2011, each week starts on saturday.

Comment: It should be adding the number of weeks specified in the 2nd parameter (23 above)... see updated sql and the results above...

Comment: Now you're adding 23 weeks and then 23 days: `dateadd(day, 23, dateadd(week, 23, '2011-01-01'))`   Not sure what that's supposed to do.

Comment: Right... I'll correct that it should be adding 7 days, Thanks

Comment: "DATEADD" is a built-in MSSQL (and TSQL) function that takes 3 parameters; the "datepart" that specifies on which part of the date to return a new value, the "number" that is used to increment the datepart, and the "date" that indicates the "start date" for the addition process.  In my example code above from the msdn site, they used 2007-01-01 as the start date... I used 2011-01-01 in first 2 examples above.

Comment: Also... the first day of the week in mssql is by default 7 (which is Sunday) so that's why this is returning the Monday values... You can reset the first day of the week for mssql by using  the "SET DATEFIRST { number | @number_var } " function...

Comment: When I do a "SELECT @@DATEFIRST from my SQL SERVER I get 7... I'm guessing you won't get that... If you're getting a Saturday, you'll probably get 5 (Friday).